# course list in combo box

Tags: mysql, moodle

i am trying to get all the courses from database but i guess its not really working can anyone tell me or give me the query to get all courses from data base

```
    $DB->get_records_menu('quiz', array('course' =>$courseid),'','id, name');
echo '<select name="quizid2" id="combo_3">';
            echo '<option value=" " selected="selected">Choose....</option>';
            foreach($quizzes as $id2 => $name) {
                echo '<option value=' . $id2 . '>' . $name . '</option>';
            }
            echo '</select>';
```

this is what i am using to get all the quizzes of specific course but somehow i am unable to get the list of all available courses from database
i want to list the courses in same way aswell

Answer (score 1):

you can use **get_courses()** to fetch all courses of site or any category.